# Error al tratar de leer ficheros en c++

Tags: c++, archivo

Tengo esta clase y hice metodos para que se guarde en un archivo, todo bien hasta ahi puedo guardar cuantos registros quiera sin que me de error, pero al tratar de leer siempre me arroja infraccion de acceso de lectura.

```
class Usuario
{
    friend int Login();
    friend void GrabarUser(Usuario&);
    //friend int VerificarUser(Usuario&);
    //friend int VerificarUser2(Usuario&);
private:
    string User;
    string Password;
public:
    ~Usuario() {

    }

    void setUser(string _User) {
        User = _User;
    }

    string getUser() {
        return User;
    }
    
    void setPassword(string _Password) {
        Password = _Password;
    }
    string getPassword() {
        return Password;
    }
    void RegistrarUser();
};
void CrearArchivo();
void GrabarUser(Usuario&);
int Login();
```

Estas son las funciones que uso para grabar el archivo

```
void Usuario::RegistrarUser() {
    string _User;
    string _Password;

    cout << "Ingrese el User: ";
    cin >> _User;
    this->setUser(_User);

    cout << "Ingrese la Contraseña: ";
    cin >> _Password;
    this->setPassword(_Password);
}

void GrabarUser(Usuario& _User) {
    FILE* PtrArchivo = fopen("Users.txt","ab");
    if (PtrArchivo == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr,"Error: No se pudo abrir el archivo");
    }
    else {
        fwrite(&_User,sizeof(Usuario),1,PtrArchivo);
    }
    fclose(PtrArchivo);
}
```

Esta es la función que uso para tratar de leer.

```
int Login() {
    Usuario est;
    string _User;
    string _Password;

    FILE* PtrArchivo = fopen("Users.txt", "r+b");
    //
    fread(&est, sizeof(Usuario), 1, PtrArchivo);
    fclose(PtrArchivo);
    return 0;
    //
    /*
    cout << "Ingrese el User: ";
    cin >> _User;

    cout << "Ingrese la Contraseña: ";
    cin >> _Password;

    if (PtrArchivo == NULL) {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error: No se pudo abrir el archivo");
        return 0;
    }
    while (!feof(PtrArchivo)){
        fread(&est, sizeof(Usuario), 1, PtrArchivo);
        cout << "1" << endl;
    }
    fclose(PtrArchivo);
    return 0;
    */
}
```

Esta es la funcion que uso para leer, en la parte comentada estaba tratando de buscar un usuario en el fichero que cree, pero luego de eso me di cuenta que me daba error de acceso solo por intentar leer con el fread , ya intente cambiar el archivo el modo de lectura y aun no se arregla.
[image: Esta una captura del error]

Answer (score 0):

Cuando llamas la función `fread` le pasas los argmentos de manera incorrecta.
El primer argumento deberia ser donde guardar lo leido (char*) el segundo el tamaño de lo que vas a leer, el tercero la cantidad y el último el archivo (FILE*).

El primer argumento es incorrecto. Aqui tienes la doc para informaciona mas detallada [man fread](https://linux.die.net/man/3/fread)

Te recomiendo usar funciones de la STL de c++ para leer archivos y escribir en ellos ya que tendras mas manejo de los datos.

Answer (score 0):

El clase contiene miembros de tipo `std::string`. No es posible leer o escribir ellas con `fread` y `fwrite`porque contienen punteros internos.

Puedes verlo porque `sizeof(Usuario)` es una constante (demasiado pequeña), pero un nombre y un contraseña pueden ser de cualquier longitud.

Necesitas encontrar una forma diferente de leer y escribir esta clase. Un usuario por *línea* es un buen método. Para leer una línea completa, puedes usar `std::getline`. Entonces, descompónla en nombre de usuario y contraseña. Usa `std::fstream`, no `FILE*`.